# How to restart app when a sub activity start from recent list in android

Tags: android, android-activity, restart, launchmode

My app has two activities.

- Main Activity : singleTask
- Sub Activity : singleInstance

When launching app with touching app icon, main activity starts. And go to sub activity then press home button. Then Kill app using task Killer. It is a point that I want restart app when user select app from recent list, but app starts from subactivity. I tried to set clearTaskOnLaunch on main activity but it doesn't work.

Does Anyone know how to solve this problem?